# android studio got stuck at 'Downloading Components' screen

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5TcP.png)

Hello everyone, I'm a flutter beginner and I'm trying to install android studio, however it got stuck at "Downloading Components" screen for a couple of hours now, presumably 3-4 hours, I would like to know why it's like that. My internet connection is okay but just don't know why it doesn't make any progress. Appreciate it if any suggestions can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not [flutter] tag, you should change it, but the most likely is your internet connection. Try open this link: http://dl.gooogle.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86_64-33_r11.zip . This is your Android Studio's download link in your image.